# Facebook SDK 4.4 and Swift - Get Started Guide

Tags: facebook, swift

Following the Getting Started guide with FB SDK integration with Swift and having a hard time getting the login button to work properly (no logout option shown). (NOTE: First time swift developer)

```
    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
      [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
    }

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
      return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    }

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
                openURL:(NSURL *)url
      sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
             annotation:(id)annotation {
      return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                             openURL:url
                                                   sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                          annotation:annotation];
    }
```

My Bridge File

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this. Now the Getting started guide works. Took me 20 minutes to figure out how to do the Objective-C -> Swift translation, so thought I would save someone else the trouble.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {        
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//initialise fb

```
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance()?.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return true

}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {


    let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication]as! String?, annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    return handled
}
```